# Invoke-RestMethod returns integer as string

Tags: powershell

I have an integer variable e.g. `$int = (1,2,3)`

I need to get that value using `Invoke-RestMethod` e.g. `$var = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata-Flavor" = "Google"} -Uri http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/numbers` the problem is, Invoke-RestMethod returns the value as a string not as an integer.

Also it's not possible to convert it to integer casting like `[int]$var = $int`
It returns an error:
*`Cannot convert value "(1,2,3)" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."`*

If I don't use Invoke-RestMethod to retrieve the value it works as expected as `$int = (1,2,3)` creates a System.Int32.

Comment: How are you using `Invoke-RestMethod` and how does that relate to anything here?  It sounds like your API is returning a string array.

Comment: `(1,2,3)` is not an integer, it's an array of integers (`int[]`). The real question is, how is the server producing that value? It would be normal to get the results back as JSON, in which case PowerShell could easily deserialize it into an array. It's *possible* to convert `(1,2,3)` to an array of integers, but the easy ways of doing so involve evaluating it as code, which is horribly unsafe if the response is arbitrary input from the internet.

Comment: Show the complete line that calls `Invoke-RestMethod` and also show the web server's response (both headers and body - you can use your browser's developer tools or something like PostMan to get this info).

Comment: Nothing special in Invoke-Restmethod, `Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata-Flavor" = "Google"} -Uri http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/numbers`

so it returns numbers value from the instance metadata key. Exact output is `(1,2,3)` type is string.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the code. Comments are not suitable for more than a few bytes of code. Hard to read.

Comment: @Gareth *"and also show the web server's response (both headers and body)"* was the second question. If the webserver really returns the string `"(1,2,3)"` then that would be a highly unusual format. I would expect something more common, like JSON.

Comment: @Tomalak since the metadata key's value is (1,2,3) it returns the same value as a string. @SysEngineer's answer `[int[]]$int = $int -replace '[()]','' -split ','` helped me to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that your `int` can be an array.

```
[int[]]$var = $int
```

Help this helps!

EDIT**

Remove the parenthesis from the string and split it at the comma.

```
[int[]]$int = $int -replace '[()]','' -split ','
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns,

`[int[]]$var = $int

Cannot convert value "(1,2,3)" to type "System.Int32[]". Error: "Cannot convert 
value "(1,2,3)" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct 
format.""`

Comment: What about splitting it up from a string? `[int[]]$int = $int -replace '[()]','' -split ','`

Comment: @Gareth Is that how you wanted it to be? and array of integers?

Comment: @Gareth no problem! Glad I could help.